# Paste Image Into TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am looking at ways to Paste an Image into TinyMCE editor, I have been googling it for a while, but couldn't find any related answer.

I can append an `<img>` with src content to the Editor(when i paste the image on the page other than inside the editor).

I am not able to paste it inside the Editor. I am using Javascript and jquery. Has anyone got an idea, how i could do this.

Comment: AFAIK you can just copy an image from a web site and paste it in TinyMCE. You talking about c&p from desktop?

Comment: Yes, i am copying an image from desktop and trying to paste it.

Comment: That is quite tricky. So far I think only google docs have that technology that too just for chrome.

Answer (score 7):

Enable [paste_data_images](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_data_images)

> Setting paste_data_images to "true" will allow the pasted images,
> while setting it to "false" will disallow pasted images.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. TinyMCE and any other editor out there are giving you the functionality of creating rich text content. Displaying an image requires an URL and there is no URL to the image on your machine.

You need to upload the image to a server. You need to be able to access that image through a link. That link is what you insert into TinyMCE.

Comment: There actually is a URL you can get with modern browsers.  You can capture the paste event, put the clipboard data onto a canvas, and request a data url from that.  I am currently working on this solution right now, but I have not proven its effectiveness yet. I'll report back soon... hopefully.

Comment: In Firefox, when you paste an image it immediately goes in as a `data:` uri. Then it is just up to the server-side to parse it...

Comment: I know this answer is old, but it's incorrect so anyone seeing this now, you can activate it with: "paste_data_images: true" in the init function.

Comment: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/paste/#paste_data_images